# Form has controls at design-time but when I run project it shows empty form

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2019, windows-forms-designer

hello i ran into this problem and i don't know how to fix it it was working just fine but now when i try to start project this is form it should show but instead [image]

it is like that only blank form[image]

please help and thank you <3

Comment: Is there any update in this issue? If you accept it, you could click '✔' to mark the reply as the accepted answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve the similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

Two common reasons :

- You forgot to call `InitializeComponent` in constructor.
- Or you have `Application.Run(new Form())` which you want `...Form1())`.